# how to check if a second has elapsed c++

Tags: c++

So I'm creating a program which needs to update a variable per second. I understand that I need the header file, "time.h", but I'm not sure what function to use.

it should work like this:

```
int main(){
    int variable;
    // Every second
        variable = variable+1;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, you can use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) to get your program (well, the current thread, strictly speaking) to pause for approximately the length of time you specify. For example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    int variable = 0;
    while (variable < 10) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); // sleep for one second
        ++variable;
    }
}
```